# CGI-LUA with lighttpd: 500 internal server error

Tags: cgi, embedded-linux, lighttpd

I'm running CGI-LUA scripts with lighttpd on embedded device. The web client attempts to run via POST three scripts every 3 seconds. 
Most of the time it works, but the issue is that from time to time I get 500 internal server error, like the server fails to run the script, though nothing changed and in the 'top' I see that the CPU is idle most of the time. 
 
I'm new to web, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were trying to solve this problem I would start with:
1) Look in /var/log/lighttpd/error.log to see what lighttpd is reporting when the failure occurs.
2) Write a very simple CGI-LUA script that does something traceable, like touch a file with the current unixtime as its name, and hit it every 3 seconds instead of your script.  This will help you figure out if the problem is in CGI-LUA or in your script.
3) Run your script outside CGI-LUA repeatedly in a loop to see if it ever fails.